# Increase performance in Lua get_table slow

Tags: arrays, performance, lua

I would like to use the lua script do to some mathematic precalculations in my application i don't want to hardcode it. I use the LUA as a DLL linked libary. Caller program code languange is not C-based language.

The application is handling pretty big array. The array is normaly (25k-65k) * 8 double number array.

My target is:

- put this array into the lua script using global variable
- read back this array from the lua script
- i would like to reach this action is less than 100ms.

Currently i tested with 28000 x 6 array but the time is 5 sec.

I am using lua_gettable function and iterating across the array, it is a huge amount of stack write and read.

My question is no have any other solution for that? I checked the API but maybe i skipped some function. Any possibilities to ask lua to put array subset into the stack? And of course the opposite way.

Thank you so much for any help and suggestion!

Comment: There's not enough info to suggest anything. No access patterns described, nor the purpose of moving data around. If you're iterating over the array, consider using `lua_next()`, you will save some time in table keys manipulation, and no explicit calls to lua_gettable is needed.

Comment: If you want to convert the array to a lua table, then yes, that's gonna be slow. Push it as a pointer (aka. userdata) with some methods to access its value, unless you really need it to be a proper table.

Comment: The purpose is, the table is represent a curve for a routes, and i would like to use some different calculation and modify the original data and put back to the system. I would like to change the script for use different method (it is deppend on the situation). I use a Kind of Mathlab so i check i can use C pointer or not (this is why i use dll)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by DarkWiiPlayer, I believe the best way to achieve this in a reasonably fast speed would be to use Lua's userdata. I did an example using a class with a double matrix with [65536][65536][8] dimensions, as you said yours would be:

```cpp
class MatrixHolder {
public:
    double matrix[65536][65536][8];
};
```

Then, I created a method to create a new MatrixHolder and another one to perform an operation in one of the positions of the matrix (passing I, J and K as parameters).

```cpp
static int newMatrixHolder(lua_State *lua) {
    MatrixHolder* object;
    size_t nbytes = sizeof(MatrixHolder);
    object = static_cast<MatrixHolder*>(lua_newuserdata(lua, nbytes));
    return 1;
}

static int performOperation(lua_State *lua) {
    MatrixHolder* object = static_cast<MatrixHolder*>(lua_touserdata(lua, 1));
    int i = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -3);
    int j = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -2);
    int k = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -1);
    object->matrix[i][j][k] += 1.0;
    lua_pushinteger(lua, object->matrix[i][j][k]);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg matrixHolderLib [] = {
    {"new", newMatrixHolder},
    {"performOperation", performOperation},
    {NULL, NULL} // - signals the end of the registry
};
```

In my computer, it executed the given Lua scripts in the following times:

```
m = matrixHolder.new()
i = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,1,1);
j = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,2,1);
i = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,1,1);
```

~845 microseconds

```
for i = 1, 1000
do 
    m = matrixHolder.new()
    i = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,1,1);
    j = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,2,1);
    i = matrixHolder.performOperation(m, 1,1,1);
end
```

~617 milliseconds

I'm unsure if it will serve your purpose, but it seems already way faster than the 5 seconds you mentioned. My computer is a 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 16 GB RAM, for comparison.

Comment: i'm not the OP, and I'm no expert, but isn't this C++?  I'm just asking because I'm reading these questions trying to learn, and also kinda wondering about C in Lua...

Comment: @poorandunlucky Yes, the userdata is obviously implemented in C++. Could be easily ported to C though. As an aside, it's misses all basic safety and comfort, look into setting a custom metatable.

Comment: Indeed, @poorandunlucky, but my code has only a few lines that make it C++, instead of C. Changing it to C shouldn't be a big issue. Since the OP didn't specify the language used (besides being not C-based), I decided to give it a try to check the performance using C-Lua binding anyway because it was easier for me to test. If the language used supports the binding and the usage of userdata, I believe the performance will increase a lot compared to using the stack as stated by OP.